# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Investipediaa\resources\views\frontend\layouts\Profile.blade.php)

Tags: database, laravel, view, controllers

I am getting this error in my view , My view source code is here. Everything was working but suddenly I am getting this error and unable to find from where this problem occurs.

There are three tables in DB Users regulars and posts  I want to retrieve the data of the authenticated user in this profile view but getting this exception.I will be highly thankful to stack overflow members for providing me the solution.

```
 <div class="panel panel-danger">
                {{--<div class="panel-heading">--}}
                {{--Danger Panel--}}
                {{--</div>--}}
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <blockquote class="col-md-3">
                        <img style="width:210px ; height: 230px " src="{{url('user.png')}}">

                        <h2>{{$user2['username']}}</h2>


                    </blockquote>
                    <div class="well col-md-9 details">


                        <h4>Email : {{$user1['email']}}</h4>
                        <h3>Phone No: {{$user2['phone_number']}}</h3>
                        <h4>Gender: {{$user2['gender']}}</h4>
                        <h4>Country: {{$user2['country']}}</h4>


                    </div>

                </div>
                {{--<div class="panel-footer">--}}
                {{--Panel Footer--}}
                {{--</div>--}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                {{--<div class="panel-heading">--}}
                {{--Danger Panel--}}
                {{--</div>--}}
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <blockquote class="col-md-3">
                            <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                            <div class="info">
                                Posted by <h4>{{$post->user->email}} </h4>on {{$post->created_at}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="interaction">
                                <a href="#">Like</a> |
                                <a href="#">Dislike</a>
                                @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                                    |<a href="#">Edit</a> |
                                    <a href="{{route('post.delete',['post_id' => $post->id])}}">Delete</a>
                            @endif

                        </blockquote>
                    @endforeach
```

My controller function for retrieving data is here . Here I am accessing data of authenticated user from 3 tables of database.

public function userProfile()
    {

```
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user1 = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();
    $user2 = Regular::where('user_id',$user_id)->first();
    $posts = Post::where('id',$user_id)->first();
    return view('frontend.layouts.Profile',compact('user1','user2','posts'));
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your Post object doesn't have a User. Have you setup relations within the Post model? Also, you're doing `first()` on Post while you're expecting a collection (you're doing foreach on $posts). Change the 'first()' to 'get()'.

Comment: Yes relations are set between user and posts models .

Comment: By changing first() into get() . It solved my problem.